# assignment works as a condition

Tags: c, visual-c++

Consider the following Code,

```
int i;
while(i=0)
    printf("Hello");
```

Now Generally speaking i=0 is an `assignment` and not a `condition` for `while` to check.
But the `GCC` compiler lets it go with a warning and even evaluates it correctly (does not execute the print statement).

Why? I usually would do with parenthesis for the truth value but my juniors feel that I am wrong and there is no real reason for the parenthesis in this!

EDIT: Zeroing down on the 'actual' doubt, Please consider the following test case

```
int callme(){
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc,char*argv[]){
    int c;
    while(c = callme()){
        printf("Calling...\n"); 
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Note that most compilers will warn you about using assignment in such context because it is often error. It would be better to have sample like `while(readCount=read(buffer))` instead of assigning constant which will always evaluate to false in your case...

Comment: It is worth pointing out that comparing to zero is completely unnecessary in C. You could write `while(i)`, and it will work just fine.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: 'while (i)` is equivalent to `while (i != 0)`, which is the opposite of the condition apparently wanted.  It is less common to miss out the `!` from `!=` than one of the `=` from `==`.  Of course, were it not for the assignment, the value of `i` would be undefined and the behaviour of the loop would be indeterminate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right, I meant `while (!i)`, not `while(i)`.

Answer (score 9):

The expression `i = 0` does 2 things:

- Has the side effect of storing o in `i`
- Yields the value 0

> I usually would do with parenthesis for the truth value but my juniors
>   feel that i am wrong and there is no real reason for the parenthesis
>   in this

It's usually a hint to the compiler meaning "I actually want this, I didn't forget a `=`, shut up".

---

For your specific case there's no reason to write `if (i = 0)`: you already know what if (0) does. But it's pretty useful when used as:

```
if ((i = some_function()))
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`i=0` is always an assignment (unless you have it as part of `int i = 0;` where it is an initialization).  But any non-void expression may appear inside the condition of a `while` loop and if it evaluates to non-zero, the body of the loop will be executed, and if it is zero, the body of the loop will not be executed.

The notation:

```
while (i = 0)
    printf("Hello\n");
```

is always equivalent to:

```
i = 0;
```

There is very little justification for writing the loop at all.

People do write other expressions:

```
while (c = getchar())
    ...process EOF or a non-null character...
```

But that's usually a bug.  It is more likely that you should be writing:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    ...process a character - possibly null...
```

or even:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\0')
    ...process a non-null character...
```

The first `getchar()` loop gets a warning from GCC; the latter two do not because of the the explicit test of the value from the assignment.

The people who write a condition like this:

```
while ((c = getchar()))
```

really annoy me.  It avoids the warning from GCC, but it is not (IMNSHO) a good way of coding.

Comment: Interesting. So you're saying you should always write explicitly `!= 0` when assigning ?

Comment: If the assignment is in a conditional (loop or `if`), then yes.  That's what the GCC warning suggests is better, too.  The assignment without the comparison is 'correct', but not always correct.  And I like my programs to compile with zero warnings even with the compiler set to fussy, so I write so that GCC does not complain.  I habitually use `-Wall -Wextra` (and usually add a few other options too, especially at work where I'm still plagued by code partially converted to prototype notation).

Comment: I also use `-Wall -Wextra` but  I guess writing the redundant parentheses does indicate your intent ? Your opinion + checkpatch.pl are starting to change my mind :-))

Comment: I suppose i end up in ur "annoying" category then.
Also I am doing while((variable=functioncall())){//do something} So as you can see the extra parenthesis check. here my colleague suggested this is not required.

Answer (score 2):

When you use an assignment operator such as

```
a=0;
```

You assign the value to 'a', and still return the number 0.

---

**To test your question, I tried these lines of codes:**

```
int a;
printf("%d", a=0);
```

and these lines displayed 0.

**Then, I tested another set of codes:**

```
int b;
printf("%d", b=15);
```

Here, the lines displayed 15.

---

**So, if you do:**

```
while(a=0)
{
    printf("zero");
}
```

The (a=0) statement would return false, thus not displaying anything.

**But if you do:**

```
while(a=15)
{
    printf("fifteen");
}
```

The "fifteen" will be displayed endlessly, because the statement (a=15) will return a non zero value, or 15, which is not false, not zero, thus it is true. :)

Answer (score 1):

As cnicutar has told above the assignment also yields the value zero.

Some additional info:

It is a common coding mistake for people to omit an extra '=' whereby the comparison becomes an assignment.

An easy way to avoid this is to write the comparison as below, in which case even if a '=' is missed compiler will give an error

```
while(0 == i)
{
  prinf("Hello");
}
```